# WooCommerce order-received redirect based on payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

Usually in WooCommerce submitted orders are redirect to `/order-received/` once payment is completed.

Is it possible to redirect customer to a custom page for a particular payment method?

For example:

```
Payment method 1 -> /order-received/
Payment method 2 -> /custom-page/
Payment method 3 -> /order-received/
```

Answer (score 4):

With a custom function hooked in **`template_redirect`** action hook using the conditional function **`is_wc_endpoint_url()`** and targeting your desired payment method to redirect customer to a specific page:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'thankyou_custom_payment_redirect');
function thankyou_custom_payment_redirect(){
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        global $wp;

        // Get the order ID
        $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) );

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Set HERE your Payment Gateway ID
        if( $order->get_payment_method() == 'cheque' ){
            
            // Set HERE your custom URL path
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/custom-page/' ) );
            exit(); // always exit
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

> **How to get the Payment Gateway ID (WC settings > Checkout *tab*):**
>
> [image]

Comment: your action will not worked correctly, because you always **exit** from `template_redirect`, you need exit after you redirected to another page `wp_redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

A small correction.

"exit" needs to be within the last condition

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'thankyou_custom_payment_redirect');
    function thankyou_custom_payment_redirect(){
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        global $wp;

        // Get the order ID
        $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) );

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Set HERE your Payment Gateway ID
        if( $order->get_payment_method() == 'cheque' ){

            // Set HERE your custom URL path
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/custom-page/' ) );
            exit(); // always exit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interested to know why my amendment was down-voted without comment, given that the original solution will produce a 500 error across an entire Woocommerce installation upon second action.